# What does # mean in a mathematical expression?

Tags: probability

What does # mean in this formula? [hn(x) = #(1 ≤ i ≤ n: xi ∈ (aj−1, aj ])/(n(aj − aj−1))][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMKUs.png)

I've tried to google it in various terms but haven't found any examples of other formulas with it, and it's also not explained in the appendices of the book I read.

Other example of usage:
[T = #(1 ≤ i ≤ n: Xi > μ0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MHsv.png)

Comment: It means "the number of".  So $\#\{1,2,6\}=3$, for example.

Comment: For a set $S$, the cardinality is denotes by $\# S$ or $|S|$.

Comment: But some people use this also in a different context, i.e., for matrices, $A^{\#}$, or $A^{\ast}$.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. @lulu, so in my first equation, hn(x) = #(1 ≤ i ≤ n: xi ∈ (aj−1, aj ])/(n(aj − aj−1)), the # refers to the number of x such that its index is between 1 and n (inclusive) and the x itself is between aj-1 and aj, right?

Comment: Well, that's hard to parse.  I have no idea what $x_i$ means nor what the $a_j$ are (nor what $j$ is, come to that).

Comment: In number theory , $n$# is the product of the primes not exceeding $n$

Answer (score 1):

The way it's used in your example suggests it means cardinality, or the the number of items in a set. It can also refer to the [counting measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure), which is essentially the same thing.